# Show that $(x_k)$ converges to $x = (x_1,....,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$ if and only if $x_{ki} \to x_i$ as $k \to \infty$ foe each $i$.

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $x_k = (x_{k1},...,x_{kn}) \in \Bbb R^n$. Show that $(x_k)$ converges to $x = (x_1,....,x_n) \in \Bbb R^n$ if and only if $x_{ki} \to x_i$ as $k \to \infty$ foe each $i$.

I can understand the fact but finding difficulty to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

If $x_k \to x$, then given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\|x_k - x\| < \epsilon$ for all $k \ge N$. Thus, for fixed $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$,

$$|x_{ki} - x_i| = \sqrt{(x_{ki} - x_i)^2} \le \|x_k - x\| < \epsilon$$

for all $k \ge N$. Therefore, the sequence $(x_{ki})_{k = 1}^\infty$ converges to $x_i$.

Conversely, if $x_{ki} \to x_i$ as $k\to \infty$ for all $i$, then given $\epsilon$, there exist $j_1,j_2,\ldots, j_n\in \Bbb N$ such that if $1 \le m \le n$, $|x_{ki} - x_i| < \epsilon/\sqrt{n}$ for all $k \ge j_m$. Let $j = \max\{j_1,\ldots, j_n\}$. For all $k \ge j$,

\begin{align}\|x_k - x\| &= \sqrt{(x_{k1} - x_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_{kn} - x_n)^2} \le \sqrt{n\max\{(x_{k1}-x_1)^2,\ldots, (x_{kn}-x_n)^2}\} \\
& = \sqrt{n}\max\{|x_{k1} - x_1|, \ldots, |x_{kn} - x_n|\}\\
& < \sqrt{n} \cdot \frac{\epsilon}{n}\\
&= \epsilon.
\end{align}

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $x_k \to x$.

Answer (score 0):

since $x_k\rightarrow x$ then given $\epsilon>0\exists m$ such that $n\geq m_k \implies d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$

so $(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{k_i}-x_i)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\epsilon$

Choose m=max$\{m_1,m_2,...m_n\}$

So $|x_{k_i}-x_i|<(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{k_i}-x_i)^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\epsilon \forall k_i\geq m$

Thus each $x_{k_i}$ is convergent

Converse is trivial